# How to list new entries and entries with new comments?

Tags: comments

Looking for a way to list new entries, from multiple channels, and existing entries that have received comments - in the last n days. I'd be really grateful for any leads on how to do this!

Best wishes
Lee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ExpressionEngine does have an easy way to [display recent comments](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/comment/index.html#displaying-recent-comments), but it sounds like that's not quite what you're looking for. You need a list of distinct *entries* having at least one comment in the last N days.

One way to accomplish this is with the [Query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/index.html):

```
{exp:query sql=
    "SELECT title
    FROM exp_channel_titles
    JOIN exp_comments
    ON exp_comments.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id
    WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(comment_date, '%Y-%m-%d') > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
    GROUP BY exp_channel_titles.entry_id"
}
    <li>{title}</li>
{/exp:query}
```

This will give a  list of entries with comments in the last 10 days.

The key pieces are the last two lines of the query where we compare the comment date against a time interval based on the current date, and then group by entry to prevent duplicates due to multiple qualifying comments on the same entry.

Comment: Thank you VERY much Alex - very kind of you to take the time to write that for me. It's exactly what I was after and I've learnt something new as well.

Comment: Glad I could help. I learned something, too!